# How to see thread name in htop?

Tags: process, htop

`htop` shows the name of process for all of its threads even a thread has a customized name. How should I force `htop` to displays customized name of threads?

Comment: What is a "customized name" of a thread?

Comment: The name which is set by `pthread_setname_np` function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<kbd>F2</kbd> → *Display options* → *Show custom thread names*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461289/change-thread-name-on-linux-htop

Comment: No need for snarky remarks, you are now the top 1 result on google.